# postgreSQL Table Inheritance

Tags: postgresql

Currently I have an **events** table that inherits four tables:

**health_problems**, **medications**, **vaccinations**, and **visits**

I am trying to formulate a query that returns all information within each of these inherited tables.

Using this query:

```
SELECT p.relname, v.*, h.*, m.*, va.*
   FROM visits v, health_problems h, medications m, vaccinations va, pg_class p
   WHERE v.tableoid = p.oid OR h.tableoid = p.oid OR m.tableoid = p.oid OR va.tableoid = p.oid;
```

Returns what seems to be duplicated information. Can anyone help point out what I may be overlooking?

EDIT: Table contents listed below

**events**

```
      id | dateEntered| petID
----------+-----------+----------
      1  | 2015-10-31|     4
      1  | 2015-10-31|     5
      1  | 2015-10-31|     5
      1  | 2015-10-31|     4
      2  | 2015-10-31|     5
      2  | 2015-11-01|     4
      2  | 2015-11-01|     4
```

**health_problems**

```
      id | dateEntered| petID   | description | dateOccurred
----------+-----------+---------+-------------+--------------
      1  | 2015-10-31|     4    | Is a CAT    | 2015-04-10
      1  | 2015-10-31|     5    |Is ALSO A CAT| 2015-04-10
```

**medications**

```
      id | dateEntered| petID   |    name     | frequency
----------+-----------+---------+-------------+--------------
      1  | 2015-10-31|     5    | Valium      | All Day E'rday
      2  | 2015-11-01|     4    | Morphine    | Whenever
```

**vaccinations**

```
      id | dateEntered| petID   | description     | dateGiven
----------+-----------+---------+-----------------+--------------
      1  | 2015-10-31|     4    |Scarlet fever pox| 2015-10-31
```

**visits**

```
      id | dateEntered| petID   | location     | dateVisited
----------+-----------+---------+--------------+--------------
      1  | 2015-10-31|     5    |Fish Hatchery | 2015-10-31
      2  | 2015-11-01|     4    |Doggy Daycare | 2015-10-31
```

EDIT:
Sample output imaged below 
[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

The pg_class table is queried to return the name of the table the entry is being pulled from.

Best,
Otterman

Comment: Please refine your question. 1. You use `visits` in your query which is not defined (is it the same as `events`?). 2. `Medications` is defined twice, which one is correct? 3. What is the desired output given the content you provided? 4. Script for creating the tables and doing inserts will also be very helpful.

Comment: What exactly do you mean with "returns duplicate information"? Can you show your result set?

Comment: Why do you query pg_class?

Comment: What are all the `OR` s doing in the where clause? (hint: rewite to JOIN-syntax)

Comment: I included those to return results from each of the tables, is there a better alternative?

Comment: What do you mean by "inherits"?  Is the "events" table the parent table?